# Google cloud load balancer host and path mapping is not working as expected

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, gcp-load-balancer

I have configured Load Balancer on Google Cloud. It was working as expected initially. then with a new requirement came in where I need to load images from a bucket when requested from a sub path.

To do so, I have updated the path rules as image below and it feels like its not working

```
https://dashboard.XXXX.com/upload/top-view-meeple-board-game-pieces.jpg // is working

https://dashboard.XXXX.com/mini/upload/top-view-meeple-board-game-pieces.jpg // is not working  and gives <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
```

The only difference is in 1st case its referring to root directory and in 2nd case its a sub directory (/mini/). and I have similar setup in the paths rules as attached in the screenshot below.

Not sure what I am missing, as per documentation I think such mapping is supported https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/url-map-concepts#wildcards-regx-dynamic

[image]

Comment: May I know where your images within the bucket is located? Is it on the root of the bucket or in sub directory (is the /mini/ folder is existing inside the bucket?)

Comment: its in sub directory (3 levels down from the root level)